Keyboard driver not printing anything on my x64 OS
I have recently made an x86-64 OS and wanted to create a keyboard driver. I made basic logic for it and make it register its handler into IRQ1 tried it no faults were made but inside QEMU when I tap a key nothing happens.  I will add my keyboard logic below.
#include "io.h"
#include "isr.h"
#include "vga.h"
#include "idt.h"

#define KEYBOARD_DATA_PORT 0x60
#define KEYBOARD_STATUS_PORT 0x64
#define KEYBOARD_IRQ 1

char scan_code_to_ascii(uint8_t scan_code); // Function declaration

static void keyboard_callback(struct interrupt_frame *frame) {
    uint8_t scan_code = inb(KEYBOARD_DATA_PORT);

    // Convert scan code to ASCII character (simplified, no shift/ctrl handling)
    char ascii_char = scan_code_to_ascii(scan_code);

    // Print the character to the screen
    if (ascii_char != 0) {
        print_char(ascii_char);
    }

    // Send End of Interrupt (EOI) signal to PIC
    outb(0x20, 0x20);
}

void init_keyboard() {
    register_interrupt_handler(IRQ1, keyboard_callback);
}

char scan_code_to_ascii(uint8_t scan_code) {
    static char ascii_table[] = {
        0, 27, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=', '\b',
        '\t', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', '\n',
        0, 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', '\'', '`', 0,
        '\\', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/', 0,
        '*', 0, ' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    if (scan_code > 58) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ascii_table[scan_code];
}

And if qemu dump is needed:
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x0e
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
Servicing hardware INT=0x20
     0: v=20 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000101414 pc=0000000000101414 SP=0010:000000000010b000 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000021
RAX=0000000000000021 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=000000000000008e RDX=0000000000101196
RSI=0000000000101196 RDI=0000000000000021 RBP=0000000000000000 RSP=000000000010b000
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=0000000000101414 RFL=00000212 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 0000000000000000 00000000 00209800 DPL=0 CS64 [---]
SS =0010 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     0000000000100250 00000017
IDT=     0000000000102000 00000fff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000104000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000010 CCD=000000000010afa8 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000500

Tried to see if registering was the problem and it might be as my isr doesnt receive a keyboard interrupt nor no keyboard interrupts show in the qemu dump. I tested print_char which worked correctly also tested if IRQ1 was masked by PIC which it wasn't.

The problem isn't in the code you are showing. The log at least tells  you that you got a timer interrupt nd then nothing else. It just so happens I saw the problem during the last question you asked but it wasn't related to your first problem. The issue is that interrupt handlers need to end with iretq to return from interrupt. You are using C functions for ISR handlers and those return with a ret. The result of using ret is that your function doesn't properly restore things like the RFLAGS including the Interrupt Flag. IF stays off after the ret and you get no more interrupts.

You need to create ISR handlers that return with IRETQ. Most people create the stubs in assembly that set up the stack frame, call a C function with a pointer to the stack frame and then do an IRETQ. The other alternative to get things going is to mark your isr handler functions (like isr32, isr33 etc) with the __attribute__((interrupt)) . This will cause an iretq to be used to return rather than a ret.

The interrupt attribute does have limitations and I generally don't recommend it. It is documented here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#index-interrupt-function-attribute_002c-x86 . I prefer to write the ISR stubs in assembler.

I see thank you i will look onto it.

Do i need to modify the keyboard registration logic after i have made these changes? As i think i modified ISR with the recommended  assembly stubs, but i still receive the timer interrupt and nothing else.

I really can't tell without seeing all the code changes you have made. Can you make your Github available again? I noticed you made it unavailable after we dealt with your last question.

Alright give me a minute.

Its inside https://github.com/CodeGuardianSOF/VortexOS

In idt.c you need to change all the entries to point to the assembly stubs. As an example from: idt_set_gate(32, (uint64_t)isr32, 0x08, 0x8E); to idt_set_gate(32, (uint64_t)isr32_stub, 0x08, 0x8E); .  This code would have to be modified to send an EOI in the handlers to properly get future interrupts.

Your interrupt stubs still need some cleanup. You need to save (before the call to a C function) and restore (after the call) all the registers. You are pushing an extra 0 in all the ISRs. You need to push an extra 0 when there is no error code.  isr8_stub should not be pushing the extra 0 because the CPU puts an error code on the stack automatically. You can see this table to see which exceptions push an error code automatically: https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions

As well you push rsp . That should be mov rdi, rsp because in the System V ABI calling convention the first parameter is passed to a function in RDI. This differs from the 32-bit C calling convention which passes all parameters on the stack. More on the 64-bit calling convention is here: https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI#x86-64 . Before calling the C functions in the stubs you should also issue a CLD instruction before the call. This is a requirement of the x86-64 ABI as well.

Are your free to check my code if its right now? Especially the stubs cleanup part, it was really time consuming.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
